# Which is the best way to parse multiple arguments command line style?

Tags: python, algorithm

I use python for programming. But this question is not language specific in that sense. I am not asking for any particular modules like 'argparse' in python. My question is how to go about handling arguments parsing in a program that accepts multiple arguments like bash commands. Some bash commands have options and arguments covering most alphabets in the english language . So far, all the programs that I have written only involve a handful of arguments and I mostly use if/else loops to handle the different arguments. But this starts getting clumsy the moment you are talking about, lets say 10 or more arguments. The other method that I have used is to match arguments against dictionary keys.

eg: `foo -aLXBpTyz`

In the above example, to create if/else loops for all the possible arguments will be too clumsy in my opinion. Which is the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: The best way is to use `argparse`.

Comment: That standard way to parse command-line arguments in Python is with `argparse`.

Comment: I am a big fan of click: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/

Comment: As I have mentioned, I know about 'argparse' module. My question is let us say that there is program with 26 options available indicated by a to z. once you receive the user arguments using argparse or any other method, which will be the best way to process the options. Like using if./else loops or dictionary key value pairs etc